# Convert json file to csv

Tags: python, json, csv

I have this simple python code that converts a json file into a csv.
I would like to convert only the first four values of each key, but i couldn't figure out how to do it.

```
import json 
import csv 
  
  
# Opening JSON file and loading the data 
# into the variable data 
with open('personas.json') as json_file: 
    data = json.load(json_file) 
  
employee_data = data['emp_details'] 
  
# now we will open a file for writing 
data_file = open('data_file.csv', 'w') 
  
# create the csv writer object 
csv_writer = csv.writer(data_file) 
  
# Counter variable used for writing  
# headers to the CSV file 
count = 0
  
for emp in employee_data: 
    if count == 0: 
  
        # Writing headers of CSV file 
        header = emp.keys() 
        csv_writer.writerow(header) 
        count += 1
  
    # Writing data of CSV file 
    csv_writer.writerow(emp.values()) 
  
data_file.close()
```

Here is an example of json file's format

```
{"emp_details":[
    {
     "DATAID":"6908443",
     "FIRST_NAME":"Fernando",
     "SECOND_NAME":"Fabbiano",
     "THIRD_NAME":"Agustin",
     "FOURTH_NAME":"", 
     "AGE": "21", 
     "EMAIL": "fer.fab@gmail.com"
    }
]}
```

And as i said, i would like to convert only the fields DATAID, FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, THIRD NAME.

Comment: What part of this is *trying* to "convert only the first four values of each key"?

Comment: Non, actually. Everything i tried just didn't work. This code converts all de values for each key. Is the question not clear enough? Sorry about that

Comment: Can you maybe provide some more insights on format of the json file? Maybe an example (can be made up data)?

Comment: Yeah sure. Thank you for taking the time of reading my question.

Comment: if you're willing to use pandas, here is a one-liner: `pd.DataFrame(employee_data, columns=['DATAID', 'FIRSTNAME', 'SECONDNAME', 'THIRD NAME']).to_csv('data_file.csv')`

Comment: if you want to stick to the existing code, you might want to use `csv.DictWriter` instead

Comment: Thank you @Marat, Pandas worked out perfectly. I am new in StackOverflow, how can i close this question?